# How to check if a user confirmed a custom modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to use backbone js to implement a Modal window, but when I run the code, it does the search every time. I thought that I could just create a variable and assign it a 1 or 0, and check for that in my code, but I can't seem to access it properly.

Here are my two files:
**ModalView.js**

```
var modalTemplate = "<div id=\"pivotModal\" class=\"modal\">" +
        "<div class=\"modal-header\"><h3><%- title %></h3><button class=\"dtsBtn close\">Close</button></div>" +
    "<div class=\"modal-body\"><h3>Are you sure you want to remove <strong>all</strong> results from your query?</h3></div>" +
    "<div class=\"modal-footer\"><button " +
    "class=\"dtsBtn cancel\">Cancel</button><button " +
    "class=\"dtsBtn confirm\">Confirm</button></div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class=\"modal-backdrop\"></div>";

var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

    defaults: {
        title: 'Not Set',
        isConfirmed: '0'
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
        this.template = _.template(modalTemplate);
        console.log('Hello from Modal View: ' + this.options.title);
    },

    events: {
        'click .close': 'close',
        'click .cancel': 'cancel',
        'click .modal-backdrop': 'close',
        'click .confirm': 'confirm',
    },


    render: function () {
        var data = {title: this.options.title}
        this.$el.html(this.template(data));
        return this;
    },

    show: function () {
        $(document.body).append(this.render().el);
    },

    close: function () {
        console.log('Closed');
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    },

    cancel: function () {
        console.log('Cancelled');
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    },

    confirm: function () {
        console.log('Confirmed');
        this.options.isConfirmed = 1;
        console.log(this.options.isConfirmed)
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    }

});
```

**modal_test.js (which runs the code above):**

```
$('.clearAll').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _title = "Confirm Action";
    //pass the value of the item we clicked on to the title variable
    var modal = new ModalView({ title : _title });
    modal.show();
    if (modal.isConfirmed === 1) {
        console.log("Confirmed equals 1")
        clearAllSearch.startSearch();
        masterSearch.startSearch();
    }
});
```

Everything works independently, but I can't get the if statement to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to implement a custom confirmation modal

A way to implement a modal is to pass a callback function to the view.

```
ModalView.show({
    title: _title,
    callback: function(confirmed) {
        if (!confirmed) return; // early return
        console.log("User confirmed")
        clearAllSearch.startSearch();
        masterSearch.startSearch();
    }
});
```

Where the view would be implemented like this:

```
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(modalTemplate),
    events: {
        'click .close': 'close',
        'click .cancel': 'close',
        'click .modal-backdrop': 'close',
        'click .confirm': 'confirm',
    },
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.options = _.extend({ title: 'Are you sure?' }, options);
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.options));
        return this;
    },
    show: function () {
        $(document.body).append(this.render().el);
        return this;
    },
    close: function () {
        this.remove();
        var cb = this.options.callback;
        if (cb) cb(false);
    },

    confirm: function () {
        this.remove();
        var cb = this.options.callback;
        if (cb) cb(true);
    }
}, {
    // Static function
    show: function(options) {
        return new ModalView(options).show();
    }
});
```

### Using promises

Instead of a callback, you could also use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but it's not available in all browsers yet. An easy alternative would be to use [jQuery deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), jQuery's implementation of promises.

```
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.options = _.extend({ title: 'Are you sure?' }, options);
        this.deferred = $.Deferred();
    },
    show: function () {
        $(document.body).append(this.render().el);
        return this.deferred;
    },
    close: function () {
        this.remove();
        this.deferred().reject();
    },

    confirm: function () {
        this.remove();
        this.deferred().resolve();
    }
```

It would standardize the way the async confirmation is handled.

```
ModalView.show({ title: _title }).then(function() {
    console.log("User confirmed")
    clearAllSearch.startSearch();
    masterSearch.startSearch();
});
```

---

## What's not working in your code?

It looks like you're calling `modal.isConfirmed` but the modal view class is putting `isConfirmed` into an `options` property.

```
this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.options);
```

It would probably return the correct value if you used `modal.options.isConfirmed` but you could possibly create a simple accessor function on the view.

```
isConfirmed: function() {
    return this.options.isConfirmed;
}
```

And since `isConfirmed` is a boolean flag, you should set it to `true`, not an arbitrary integer like `0` or `1`.

Then you could call `if (modal.isConfirmed())` and it would return the correct value.

Though, you're having another problem: the moment the modal is shown and the moment the user has interacted with the modal are **asynchronous**.

```
var modal = new ModalView({ title : _title });
modal.show();
// This will always be false since the user hasn't clicked anything yet.
if (modal.isConfirmed === 1) {
```

This is fixed with the callback technique shown first.

---

## Other possible improvements

You're creating the template function each time you instantiate the modal view when you could do it once while defining the class.

```
var ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(modalTemplate), // define the template here
    initialize: function (options) {
        // this.options = options; // useless line
        this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
    },
```

Comment: So the isConfirmed function always returns a value, so how do I check to see if the value is 1? I tried wrapping the return into an if statement with a return false if it is not a value of one, but that didn't work.

Comment: @JustinBoucher missed the async problem when I looked at it first. So I updated my answer with a full solution instead of a patch to your code.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had to move some things around, because they are specific to Splunk, but this was a perfect solution. Thank you!